# Spring Boot Security JWT custom authentication error messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

How to send different error messages on JWT authentication failure? I tried below code, its always sending message as: `Full authentication is required to access this resource`
instead I want to use errorMessage from exception. I am using spring boot 3 (if it matters)

WebSecurityConfig.class:

```
 @Bean
public AuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    return (request, response, error) -> {
        log.info("restAuthenticationEntryPoint: {}", error.getMessage(), error);
        Map<String, Object> errorObject = new HashMap<>();
        int errorCode = 401;
        errorObject.put("message", error.getMessage());
        errorObject.put("error", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        errorObject.put("code", errorCode);
        errorObject.put("timestamp", new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setStatus(errorCode);
        response.getWriter().write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(errorObject));
    };
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .disable()
            .httpBasic()
            .disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .and()
            .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
 
    return http.build();
}
```

At JWT validation, I am throwing different messages, still client is receiving same error message.

```
 public DecodedJWT decodeJWT(String authToken) {
    try {
        return verifier.verify(authToken));
    } catch (SignatureVerificationException e) {
        log.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (TokenExpiredException e) {
        log.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (MissingClaimException e) {
        log.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (JWTDecodeException e) {
        log.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (AlgorithmMismatchException | IncorrectClaimException e) {
        log.error("JWT alg mismatch or incorrect claim : {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InvalidClaimException e) {
        log.error("InvalidClaimException");
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (JWTVerificationException e) {
        log.error("JWTVerificationException at end");
        throw new TokenException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

TokenException class:

```
public class TokenException extends AuthenticationException {
 public TokenException(String msg, Throwable cause) {
    super(msg, cause);
 }

 public TokenException(String msg) {
    super(msg);
 }
}
```

Comment: Throwing helpfull error messages duric any type of authentication is a security risk as this aids users with malicious intents to understand what they have done wrong and adapt. All security issues should return a 403 FORBIDDEN with no error message when something is wrong

Comment: How can client differentiate when to send refresh token request? Lets say I want to signal my client when token is expired so that it can request a new access token sending a refresh token. This would be possible if I can send different messages to client.

Comment: By you returning a 401/403 and your client automatically tries to refresh once

Comment: you see your client will get a token, use that token until it expires, when it expires your service will get a 401 bacck, you then in your client try to refresh it once, if it works it redoes the request, if the refresh failes, it redirects the user to the login page. You dont need any specific information to the client.

Answer (score 0):

This exception throws from tokenAuthenticationFilter class. Note that the filter class won't stop even if an exception occurs. Your filter class will just ignore your exception.

How to stop when exception occurs?
When you're calling decodeJwt(); method. You should put this method inside try-catch. If exception is catched then you should call sendError(); method from HttpServletResponse class and put return; method.

> Add return; even method is void

```
DecodedJWT decodedJWT = null;
try {
  decodedJWT = jwtUtils.decodeJWT(token);
} catch(Exception e) {
  response.sendError(401, e.getMessage);
  return;
}
```

add this code above to your filter class

Comment: With the above snippet, the response is 403 always and the body is empty in postman though we are sending `401` !

Comment: You have to include 'server.error.include-message: always' to your application.properties file. @Forece85